# Look for any array from a file and edit its elements python

Tags: python, arrays, list, element

I have a txt file that has many lines among there is an array whose I know the name but don't know its elements, like:
names = ["name1", "name2"]
When I find it, I want to edit its elements by appending a string to each of them,

> like: names = ['{0}-familyname'.format(element) for element in names]

How could I do that ?

Comment: It's hard t answer this question without knowing more what the line in question looks like. For instance, are you able to extract the string as `names = ["name1", "name2"] ` or do you need to do extra work. Is there anything else in the line?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it by just iterating through the list, and then adding the desired string to each of them such as below:
`

```
list_tst = ['name1', 'name2']

for d in range(len(list_tst)):
    list_tst[d] += "added text"
```

`
I am not completely sure of it, but this is all that came to my mind

Comment: I actually have a file in which I want to identify an array whose I know the name and then append the string to its elements